# AngularJS ng-repeat not rendering $resource

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ui-router

I'm working on an Angular app that includes a user feed page, one of the items on the feed is a list of groups that the user belongs to.  The groups are pulled from the backend through a $resource call that accepts the user id as parameters.

The issue I am facing is that allGroups (the collection returned by the $resource call) is available in the $scope but is not rendering on the page.

Here is the controller that is setting the groups variable:

```
angular.module('kickitAngularFrontendApp')
  .controller('UserCtrl', function ($timeout, $scope, User, $rootScope) {
    $timeout(function() {
      User.allGroups.query({user_id: $rootScope.user.id}, function(data) {
        $scope.allgroups = data;
      })
    }, 130);
  });
```

Here is the User factory

```
angular.module('kickitAngularFrontendApp')
  .factory('User', function ($resource) {
    return {
      allGroups: $resource('http://localhost:3000/api/users/:user_id/get_groups', {
        query: { method: 'GET', params: {}, isArray: false }
      }),
      groupsCreated: $resource('http://localhost:3000/api/users/:id/get_groups_created', {
        query: { method: 'GET', params: {}, isArray: false }
      }),
      allEvents: $resource('http://localhost:3000/api/users/:id/get_events', {
        query: { method: 'GET', params: {}, isArray: false }
      }),
      eventsCreated: $resource('http://localhost:3000/api/users/:id/get_events_created', {
        query: { method: 'GET', params: {}, isArray: false }
      }),
    };
  });
```

Here is the view that is rendering the groups

```
<div class="col-md-3">
  <h3>Group Feed</h3>
  <ul class="list-group" ng-controller="UserCtrl">
    <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="group in allGroups"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I can see that the allGroups object is attached to the UserCtrl $scope and view it with ng-inspector but it will not render on the page.  My thought is that because the $resource request requires the id of the $rootScope.user object which is set after the page loads it is not available to be rendered.

If this is indeed the case, how would I go about solving it?  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Also, I am using Angular ui-router if that helps.

Comment: angular can resolve resource promisse, you not need $timeout, try `$scope.allgroups = User.allGroups.query({user_id: $rootScope.user.id});`

Comment: also in script you use `allgroups` but in markup `allGroups`

Comment: Thank you!  I had misnamed the variables heh, sometimes you just need a second pair of eyes.  And it's not to resolve the promise its to resolve $rootScope.user.id, it seems the queries are done before $rootScope.user is available.

Comment: it not clear what you mean _its to resolve $rootScope.user.id,_ can you provide sample?

Comment: It = $timeout. If `$scope.allgroups = User.allGroups.query({user_id: $rootScope.user.id});` is not wrapped in a $timeout $rootScope is undefined when the $resource is queried and I end up with a get request to /user/undefined/groups.

Comment: By forcing the query to wait 130ms after the page loads to make the query $rootScope is defined and the url is correct.  If there is a better way I'm all ears, it definitely feels a little hacked together lol.

Comment: `$rootScope` can't be _undefined_. possibly you mean `$rootScope.user`? can you provide how you work with `$rootScope.user`?